# Trouble with setting background color for Line chart at Chartjs version 3.5.1

Tags: angular, chart.js

I've updated my chartjs version to 3.5.1 and I cant set my background color for line chart. Border color is still active. Here is my code:

```
const labels = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
    fill: true,
  }]
};
this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: this.options,
})
```

And the result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJOxM.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is because you set a borderColor, if you remove that line from your dataset it won't be set

Comment: @LeeLenalee Sorry but I dont get what you say. Now I want both borderColor and backgroundColor, but I only get the borderColor

Comment: Didn&#39;t notice the fill true, since backgroundColor did apply to the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me. Only thing I can think of is that you are using treeshaking import and don't have the filler plugin imported and registered like so:

```js
import { Chart, Filler } from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(Filler)
```

Alternatively you can also let chart.js import and register everything so you don't encounter these kind of problems like so:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```